# linq with having and sub query

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

How can I write a linq to entities query that includes a having and sub query? 
For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   dbo.Gavahi g 
WHERE  g.id  NOT IN (
    SELECT    GavahiID
    FROM      dbo.AsnadMaliDetail  ad 
    GROUP BY  GavahiID 
    HAVING SUM (MablaghMoredEstefade) >= (
        SELECT mablagh
        FROM   dbo.Gavahi g 
        WHERE  g.id = ad.GavahiID
    )
)
```

Comment: can you please improve the formatting? and what have you got so far?

Comment: Please, research about linq and try to do something. And then if you could not do, then ask with your code. This is the better for you.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, it is better to investigate how to manipulate sets using LINQ instead of thinking in SQL and then trying to find a suitable translation. Microsoft tried to use SQLish names for the LINQ methods but the truth is that they are not THAT similar.

The following LINQ query does what you are expressing in SQL, assuming that GavahiId is a foreign key for Gavahi.Id:

```
var mablaghs = AsnadMaliDetails
        .GroupBy(x => x.Gavahi)
        .Where(g => g.Sum(y => y.MablaghMoredEstefade) < g.Key.Mablagh)
        .Select(x => x.Key);
```

Note that inverting the condition on the SUM of MablaghMoredEstefade, allows to select the `GroupBy` key (the Gavahi) directly, instead of juggling with primary keys `NOT IN` somewhere else.

If you are new to LINQ but you are fluent in SQL, I recommend you to try [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), it allows you to see the generated SQL at a glance. The free version does not include auto-complete, though.